# Silverlight custom Tabcontrol Design

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010, tabcontrol, out-of-browser

I am Newbie to development and am going to develop a Windows-based project using Silverlight.

I chose to make an OOB app (silerlight Out Of Browser application). In my project I am going to use a TabControl.

I am able to display a TabControl with the help of MSDN document and have Dynamically added TabItems in TabControl.

**My problem is**

in my TabControl only one TabItem should be fixed **like Google chrome Plus button** but couldn't find any tutorials or documentation for this. If I found anything that may be a third party tabcontrol.

and one more thing, if I add more TabItems I want it to be added to new line instead of scrolling.

Please provide some guidance to fix my problems.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by one TabItem should be fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to dig in to styles and templates.

Use the default template as a starting point

[MSDN: TabControl Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645035%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: -1 @Michael9000: That is not helpful. Might as well suggest Google as an answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean something like these images (with a **+** button to the right of any tabs):
[image: Two tabs]
[image: Five tabs]

I used blend to edit the TabItem template and put the TabPanelTop control part into a horizontal stack panel and added a button after the part. Xaml for the template below but the change is this part:

```
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
       <System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:TabPanel x:Name="TabPanelTop" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="24"/>
       <Button Content="+" Width="20"/>
  </StackPanel>
```

### Full modified TabControl template Xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TabControlStyle1" TargetType="sdk:TabControl">
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="sdk:TabControl">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualTop">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualBottom">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualLeft">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualRight">
                                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid x:Name="TemplateTop" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:TabPanel x:Name="TabPanelTop" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="24"/>
                                <Button Content="+" Width="20"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10" Grid.Row="1">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentTop" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualTop" Background="#8CFFFFFF" CornerRadius="0,0,3,3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="TemplateBottom" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:TabPanel x:Name="TabPanelBottom" Margin="2,-1,2,2" Grid.Row="1" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentBottom" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualBottom" Background="#8CFFFFFF" CornerRadius="3,3,0,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="TemplateLeft" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:TabPanel x:Name="TabPanelLeft" Margin="2,2,-1,2" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="0,3,3,0" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentLeft" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualLeft" Background="#8CFFFFFF" Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="0,3,3,0" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid x:Name="TemplateRight" Visibility="Collapsed">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <System_Windows_Controls_Primitives:TabPanel x:Name="TabPanelRight" Grid.Column="1" Margin="-1,2,2,2" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                            <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3,0,0,3" MinWidth="10" MinHeight="10">
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentRight" Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                            <Border x:Name="DisabledVisualRight" Background="#8CFFFFFF" CornerRadius="3,0,0,3" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="0" Opacity="0" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

When it comes to template editing even coders should get to know and love Expression Blend. It may seem like a designer-only tool, but it is worth its weight in gold for the WYSIWYG editing.

*Note: This does not address the issue of responding to the button press, but I know you can *template bind* a button's command to attached properties as well as view models, so that should be the least of your problems now.